# blockchain.com api | How generate "Legacy" & "Nested SegWit" & "Native SegWit" addresses for receive separately?

Tags: blockchain.info, api, address-generation

Please check out this link :
https://www.blockchain.com/api/api_receive
As you see we can generate receiving addresses for our customers using this api.

My question is what is the type of that generated address?
"Legacy" or "Nested SegWit" or "Native SegWit"?

My other question is : is there a way to generate "Legacy" & "Nested SegWit" & "Native SegWit" addresses for receive separately?

Comment: There's one legacy address there. I see nothing else. Site is famous for being pro large blockers' fork, I think...